# xslt xml html: how to distinguish the same elements with or without child?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The problem is I want to distinguish same elements name with different situation. For example:

```
<element>Hello StackOverFlow</element>
<element>
  <group>
     <ge>hello g1</ge>
     <ge>hello g2</ge>
  </group>
  <group>
     <ge>hello g3</ge>
     <ge>hello g4</ge>
  </group>
</element>
```

I want to have elements with text convert into

```
<div class="text_element">Hello StackOverFlow</div>
```

and for those elements with child nodes:

```
<div class="element">
  <ul class="group">
     <li>hello g1</li>
     <li>hello g2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="group">
     <li>hello g3</li>
     <li>hello g4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, the problem is how can I distinguish these two kind of elements in writing the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use count the descendant elements to see whether or not it has children, e.g. `count(descendant::group)=0`

The XSLT (assuming a root node `xml` on your input):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- No children -->
    <xsl:template match="element[count(descendant::group)=0]">
        <div class="text_element">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- With children -->
    <xsl:template match="element[count(descendant::group)&gt;0]">
        <div class="element">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="group"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <ul class="group">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ge"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ge">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the output

```
<div class="text_element">Hello StackOverFlow</div>
<div class="element">
  <ul class="group">
    <li>hello g1</li>
    <li>hello g2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="group">
    <li>hello g3</li>
    <li>hello g4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While not wrong, `element[*]` is far preferable to `element[count(descendant::group)&gt;0]` in terms of simplicity, readability, efficiency and the spirit of XSLT.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin thanks - yes, I was being rather explicit. Not quite sure what OP's real 'filter' is.

Comment: this is the exact answer i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

One simple way:  write one template with `match="element[normalize-space(text())]"` and one with `match="element[*]`.  The first matches `element` elements with text-node children that aren't just whitespace; the second matches `element` elements with element children.

Comment: Silly you, @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, you only provided the essential elements of the solution. You didn't write the whole stylesheet for him. You'll never get your answers approved that way!

Answer (score 1):

**This shorter and simpler transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="element[not(*)]">
   <div class="text_element"><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="element">
  <div class="element">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="group">
    <ul class="group">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ge">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided XML fragment wrapped into a single top element to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <element>Hello StackOverFlow</element>
    <element>
        <group>
            <ge>hello g1</ge>
            <ge>hello g2</ge>
        </group>
        <group>
            <ge>hello g3</ge>
            <ge>hello g4</ge>
        </group>
    </element>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="text_element">Hello StackOverFlow</div>
<div class="element">
   <ul class="group">
      <li>hello g1</li>
      <li>hello g2</li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="group">
      <li>hello g3</li>
      <li>hello g4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```